# Curious behaviour with ExecuteBatch and Prepared Statements

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a curious problem involving both executeBatch and Prepared Statements using JDBC to place large amounts of data into a PostgSQL database. I'm using executeBatch to send 50,000 statements to the database each time.

I know execute batch and prepared statements are working; some data is making its way into the database.
The prepared statement is

```
  INSERT INTO time ( time_id, log_id, phenomenon_time, qc_phenomenon_time )
  SELECT nextval( 'time_seq' ), ?, ?, ?
```

and using this with execute batch, the data is found in the database.

When using the follwing prepared statement,

```
  INSERT INTO result_3d ( result_3d_id, time_id, variable_id, value, qc_value ) 
  SELECT nextval( 'result_3d_seq' ), ( SELECT t.time_id 
                                       FROM time t 
                                       WHERE t.log_id = ? 
                                       AND t.phenomenon_time = ? ), ?, ?, ?
```

with execute batch there is no data in the database. I have even turned on database logging and found everything for the first but nothing for the second. The second prepared statement relys upon the data for the first, but the database is not even seeing the second.

There are no exceptions being thrown. The only curious this is that for the second prepared statement, the returned array has a size of zero. The excute batch returns immediately. Is the subquery in the second prepared statement allowed?

I am using postgres-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar as the JDBC driver against PostgreSQL v8.3.19 database.

Please help.

Comment: `set log_statement = 'all'` in postgresql.conf and restart/reload Pg, if you haven't already. Add `loglevel = 2` to the PgJDBC parameters you pass when creating the connection. Then examine the PgJDBC logs (logged via whatever java logging you have in place) and Pg logs (in `pg_log` in the datadir, or in `/var/log/`).

Comment: More info would help too: Does this happen when testing an old PgJDBC against that database too? How about when testing a new PgJDBC against a current Pg? You need to test these configurations to isolate the fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because the symptoms I have described have nothing to do with Execute Batch or Prepared Statements. During some refactoring I left out a crutial statement.

```
this.preparedStatement.addBatch();
```

So this is my bad. The symptoms describe beautifully the behaviour of the code with the missing statement.

I appreciate the effort in your comments. Some have given me new areas to study. Thanks Erwin.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the JDBC driver, but it looks suspicious that you use version 9.1 and connect to the outdated PostgreSQL 8.3.19. Upgrading PostgreSQL to 9.1 might fix your problem.

Generally, if you have defined the columns `time.time_id` and `result_3d.result_3d_id` as [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) columns (as you probably should), or if you have set the DEFAULT value for those columns to `nextval()` on the respective sequence manually, there is no need to fetch the id from the **sequences**. The values will **filled in automatically**.

> Is the subquery in the second prepared statement allowed?

Yes, it is - in principal. But it may never return **more than one row**. You must guarantee uniqueness for `(t.log_id, t.phenomenon_time)` or add `LIMIT 1`:

```
(SELECT t.time_id 
 FROM time t 
 WHERE t.log_id = ? 
 AND t.phenomenon_time = ?
 LIMIT 1)
```

With PostgreSQL 9.1 you could chain the two `INSERT` commands together with a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), which should be quite a bit faster and obviate the need for the subquery to begin with:

```
WITH data (log_id, phenomenon_time, qc_phenomenon_time
          ,variable_id, value, qc_value ) AS (
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  -- cast to appropriate types!
    )
    , i AS (
    INSERT INTO time (log_id, phenomenon_time, qc_phenomenon_time)
    SELECT log_id, phenomenon_time, qc_phenomenon_time
    FROM   data
    RETURNING time_id, log_id, phenomenon_time 
    )
INSERT INTO result_3d (time_id, variable_id, value, qc_value) 
SELECT i.time_id, d.variable_id, d.value, d.qc_value
FROM   data d
JOIN   i USING (log_id, phenomenon_time);
```

All of this may or may not fix the underlying problem, but there is a good chance it will.

My first notion was that the underlying problem could be a concurrency problem - meaning that the second `INSERT` is started before the first one is committed. But if the database does not even see the second call, there must something else at work here.

Comment: I'm trying to do a regresion test, hence a later driver with an earlier database.

Comment: The subquery in the 2nd is highly likely to return only one row, but since the db is not even seeing it, the db cannot check constraints. While the data-modfying CTE is interesting it is not suitable here. The 1st statement is executed, say, 1M time to populate the time table. The 2nd statement is executed 1M times for an unbvound number of variables. Something did happen with the 2nd statement because I had a data type mismatch. But it is not executing at all now.

Comment: It is fine to use a later JDBC driver version with an earlier server version; just don't do it the other way around. http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current

Comment: Adding a `LIMIT` to the subquery is a pretty unsafe workaround without an `ORDER BY` as well; it'll lead to unpredictable and non-repeatable behaviour. cc @BrettWalker

Comment: @CraigRinger: Adding `LIMIT 1` would just be to fix the error. If the subquery can return multiple rows, the whole setup would need rethinking. The proposed CTE would eliminate the potential point of failure.